# Problems from the Kourovka Notebook that undergraduate students can fully appreciate

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question, big-list

> [*The Kourovka Notebook*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0300) is a collection of open problems in Group
>   Theory.

My question is: could you point out some (a "big-list" of) problems [by referencing them] presented in this book that are, in principle, accessible to undegraduate students: *i.e.*, problems that refer to (and possibly might be solved by applying) definitions, concepts, and theorems that are presented in a book like Herstein's *Topics in Algebra* (and then, by extension, in an abstract algebra course for undergraduates).

The aim of this question is to allow undergraduate students to have a better understanding of current research in algebra by letting them see concretely open problems that can be easily related to known concepts.

Comment: How can I narrow the question?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by theoretically accessible. Do you just mean that the relevant definitions could be understood?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, this is pretty much what I meant.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft To be honest, I would like to know if *there exist* such problems in the book to begin with.

Comment: I don't have such a list, but if you just want an example where the _formulation_ of the problem may be understood from the definitions expected to be known to undergraduates, then what about, for example, problems like 8.10, 11.10, 16.3 ? Just randomly picked up three of them during random scrolling over the pdf.

Comment: The two very first problems are easy to understand for anyone with a basic background in group theory.

Comment: 18.49 is another simply formulated example of a problem.

Comment: I suggest to reformulate the title to better reflect what does "accessible to non-specialists" mean (i.e. "described in a way accessible to undegraduate maths students"). Then the question may give details on prerequisites they have (e.g. knowledge of definitions of a group, subgroup, conjugacy classes etc). I agree that there is a pedagogical value in knowing such examples from Kourovka, e.g. to say "this is a known theorem, and that is a slight variation of it which is an open problem" or to formulate an exercise like "check this conjecture for all finite groups of order up to N" etc.

Comment: Also, what about problems 8.85, 15.83, 17.76, 18.56 ?

Comment: Would you mind making this question a community wiki and suggesting to post one problem per answer?

Comment: I do suggest to make this question a community wiki so that all future answers will automatically become community wiki too. If you like, you may even suggest to post strictly one problem per answer - it may be interesting to see them ordered by a number of votes. Otherwise, getting upvotes just for copying a problem description from Kourovka does not seem fair. Of course, I can post my own answers as CW anyhow, but I've never heard back from you regarding the problems I've mentioned in comments above...

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov, sorry it took me so long to reply. I've flagged the question for mod attention. Also, the problem you mentioned are fine in my opinion. It would be great if you could find other interesting examples. :)

Comment: @Dal: no problem, good to hear from you, thanks :) I've posted one for now, will likely be back later with a couple of more. Would be nice to see answers evolving eventually into more detailed descriptions of the history of the problem, known difficulties, pitfalls, partial answers and other considerations - and hopefully in some cases even problems solved ;)

Comment: Speaing as a 'non-specialist' (though not an undergraduate), I think that 4.13 ('prove that every non-abelian $p$-group admits an outer automorphism of order $p$') is a nicely understandable one.  If I hit a small handful more I'll convert this into an answer...

Comment: Please avoid the tags [tag:undergraduate-research] and [tag:research]. We are trying to remove them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Problem 8.10(a)** from the 8th edition (1982):

> Is the group $G = \langle a, b \mid a^n=1, ab = b^3 a^3 \rangle$ finite or infinite for $n = 7$? All other cases known. See Archive, 7.7 and 8.10 b. (*D. L. Johnson*)

**Remark:**

- for $n=3$ the group has the order 6 (should be an easy exercise for a student to check this by hand and show that it's cyclic)
- for $n=6$ it has the order 9072 (perhaps not so easy to check this by hand, but can be done using computer).
- for $n=7$, the computer calculation runs too long without an answer.
- It is known that $G$ is infinite for:

  - $n = 15$ in [D. J. Seal, Proc. Roy. Soc. Edinburgh (A), 92 (1982), 181–192]
  - $n = 9$ (and $15$) in [M. I. Prishchepov, Commun. Algebra, 23 (1995), 5095–5117].

An example in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) illustrates the problem:

```
gap> F:=FreeGroup("a","b");
<free group on the generators [ a, b ]>
gap> G:=F/ParseRelators(GeneratorsOfGroup(F),"a^3=1,ab=b^3*a^3");
<fp group on the generators [ a, b ]>
gap> Size(G); # could be easily done by hand
6
gap> G:=F/ParseRelators(GeneratorsOfGroup(F),"a^6=1,ab=b^3*a^3");
<fp group on the generators [ a, b ]>
gap> Size(G);
9072
gap> G:=F/ParseRelators(GeneratorsOfGroup(F),"a^7=1,ab=b^3*a^3");
<fp group on the generators [ a, b ]>
gap> IsFinite(G);
#I  Coset table calculation failed -- trying with bigger table limit
#I  Coset table calculation failed -- trying with bigger table limit
... GAP was interrupted ...
```

The message about the coset table calculation hitting the limit is often a slight hint towards the fact that it may be infinite, but that's far from being the evidence - it is still possible that the calculation will succeed after increasing the limit several times.

Thus, the problem for $n=7$ is still open...

---

**Update**: the answer to this question is given now in the 7th revision of the 18th edition of the Kourovka Notebook (http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0300):

> This group is infinite, because it contains the Fibonacci group $F(3, 7)$ as an index $7$ subgroup. This follows from Theorem 3.0 of (C. P. Chalk, Commun. Algebra 26, no. 5 (1998), 1511–1546) by standard technique for working with Fibonacci groups (G. Williams, Letter of 6 October 2015).

Comment: From 1982... is this still open?

Comment: @Lopsy: yes, still open according to the [18th edition](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0300) (2014), see page 27 there. BTW, the 1st edition was published in 1965, and as Preface to the 18th edition says, "Maybe the most striking illustration of its [i.e. Kourovka Notebook] success is the fact that more than $3/4$ of the
problems from the first issue have now been solved."

Answer (score 8):

**Problem 17.76** from the 17th edition (2010):

> Does there exist a finite group $G$, with $|G| > 2$, such that there is exactly one
>   element in $G$ which is not a commutator? (*D. MacHale*)

Answer (score 8):

**Problem 15.99** from the 15th edition (2002):

> Let $f(n)$ be the number of isomorphism classes of finite groups of order $n$. Is it true that the equation $f(n) = k$ has a solution for any positive integer $k$? The
>   answer is affirmative for all $k \le 1000$ [G. M.Wei, Southeast Asian Bull. Math., 22,
>   no. 1 (1998), 93–102]. (*W. J. Shi*)

Answer (score 6):

**Problem 18.49** from the 18th edition (2014):

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Is it true that for any $a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $1 < a, b, c \le n-2$ the symmetric group $S_n$ has elements of order $a$ and $b$ whose product has order $c$? (*S. Kohl*)

---

**Update**: the 7th revision of the 18th edition of the Kourovka Notebook (http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0300) says that the answer is positive and refers to the preprint [A note on the product of two permutations of prescribed orders](http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02170) by Joachim König. From the abstract:

> We prove a conjecture by Stefan Kohl on the existence of triples of permutations of bounded degree with prescribed orders and product 1. This result leads to an existence result for covers of the complex projective line with bounded degree and prescribed ramification indices.

See also https://mathoverflow.net/q/118092/

---

**Update 2**:
19th edition of the Kourovka notebook (https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0300) gives a reference: A note on the product of two permutations of prescribed orders, J.König, Eur. J. Comb., 57 (2016), 50–56, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejc.2016.03.006.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/q/118092/ - the update of Sep 2, 2015 says that "On Aug 10, 2015
[Joachim König](http://www.mathematik.uni-wuerzburg.de/~koenig/) has posted
a [preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02170) to the arXiv which gives
a positive answer to the question. Assuming that this preprint is correct,
this completely answers the question -- and thus also Problem 18.49 in the
[Kourovka Notebook](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0300)."